# compiling armadillo with Rtools/MinGW

Tags: r, mingw, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying in vain to compile the armadillo linear algebra library for windows. Using the armadillo-4.200.0 source, I have Rtools-3.1 installed and in the path, msys from MinGW installed.

Because my ultimate goal is to use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo, my thought is that I need to use the same compiler for making armadillo as will be used to compile my Rcpp/RcppArmadillo files. Unfortunately, when trying to compile armadillo:

```
$ ./configure
[...snip...]
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CXX compiler: cl
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.

CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "cl" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
[...snip...]
```

(I tried setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` to my Rtools `gcc.exe` with no luck.)

I believe that it is looking for the visual C compiler, though the docs imply that it can be done solely with the mingw or cygwin compiler environments.

Either:

1. Is there a problem with compiling the armadillo library and subsequent Rcpp code with different versions of the compiler? (Rtools-3.1 has gcc version 4.6.3, MinGW has gcc version 4.8.1.)
2. Is there a clean method for compiling armadillo with just the Rtools collection?

(Win7 x64, R-3.1.0, cygwin gcc 4.8.2, rtools 3.1 with gcc 4.6.3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RcppArmadillo ships its own copy of Armadillo to avoid exactly this problem.  As RcppArmadillpo is used from R, it can rely on R (and R's configuration) to get LAPACK, BLAS, etc pp.  We don't need to run configure to use Armadillo from R, and so we don't do.

RcppArmadillo installs the usual `R CMD INSTALL ...` way; this is tested before every release and has worked reliably.

As you say *"your ultimate goal is to use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo"*, you are in fact done at the `R CMD INSTALL ...`.  You can replicate the step from source, and test the package -- all that should "just work".

The other thing to keep in mind is what the "Writing R Extensions" and "R Installation and Administration" manuals have to say about your compiler.  As far is R is concerned, your g++ 4.8.* does not exist. Only the Rtools version matters, or you get into non-standard land real quick.

Comment: Ahh, crap. For some reason, I thought I had to compile armadillo myself before installing RcppArmadillo. I tried so hard to RTM before posting this, too ... Thanks, Dirk, both for the answer and for `Rcpp*`.

Comment: No mas -- if you think of a place where we should say this more clearly, outside of DESCRIPTION file which already says "_The RcppArmadillo package includes the header files from the templated Armadillo library. Thus users do not need to install Armadillo itself in order to use RcppArmadillo._" then let us know.

Comment: Hehe, nice (soft but well-deserved) dig :-) I normally (mis)interpret "headers" to mean `*.h` and not the library as well, so perhaps I need to update my internal glossary. (The verbiage that would have done it for me is "*... includes the **library and** header files from ...*," but that's just my umwelt.)

Comment: Well that is the key: There *is no library* with RcppArmadillo. We use it differently from Armadillo -- that is what my answer above was trying to get at. Hence the package is just _templated headers_ which, in its geeky code, says no library too.  Do a build of an RcppArmadillo using package and you will not see `libArmadillo` anywhere as it is not used. Just templates.

Comment: A likely source of my misinterpretation: from [Arma](http://arma.sourceforge.net/): "*Armadillo is a C++ linear algebra library ...*". I had already done a quick scan and found a `.dll` in `libs` but now see it's yours, not Conrad's. Now on to adapting my model from 4D to something a little more palatable. (Nothing like the 10D matrices I've seen you comment on elsewhere.)

Comment: Yes, and to beat that dead horse one more time: Armadillo is a library, RcppArmadillo is not.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the package still has a small library because it ships a tiny bit of example code.  But that too is generated by `R CMD INSTALL ...`.